# Boostrap horizontal gaps between cols issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I'm using Bootstrap collapse to create some panels as in the picture below. However, I'd like the vertical spacing between these panels to be always the same independently of their height closed or expanded:

[image]

Below is an example of the structure of these panels. So all panels share the same code apart from the content bit.

```
<div class="homepageWidget col-md-6 contact-widget ui-sortable-handle" order="1," id="reportsWidget" data-description="List of reports">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Work Reports
                <div class="box-icons">
                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="chevron-up-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="expand-icon hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                    <span class="move-icon hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                </div>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The problems here is the col-md-6. As each of them is on a col-md-6 and their height varies the vertical spacing between cols won't be the same.

Is there a way to achieve this and still maintain the move, expand and close panel functionality?

Comment: You should put them into columns instead of rows

Comment: Your title and post don't align. Also, you're asking for a violation of the laws of space and time. You cannot have horizontal alignment _and_ vertical alignment if differently-sized elements. Pick one.

Comment: Surely there must be a way. I'm wondering if it could be achieved keeping this structure though.

Comment: It cannot. This question comes up regularly. It's fairly obvious that if you raise the row below to close the gap under the shorter card the taller card would be cut off. What else are you expecting to happen?